# Syntax error of SQL-statement

Tags: mysql, pdo

I try to get all rows which has a timestamp bigger then a value given in a variable or "0".

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC, parent, cat WHERE timest >= :low OR timest = 0');
$pdo->bindParam(':low', $low, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$pdo->execute();
```

What is wrong with that?

I get a SQLState error 42000 (syntax error), but I don't understand why.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, the order of the clauses is SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY. You swap ORDER BY and WHERE by adding some columns after ORDER BY. Please order the parts of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE timest >= :low OR timest = 0
ORDER BY id DESC, parent, cat
```

The query base "format"/grammar is :

```
select [...]
[from ... [inner | left | right ] join ... [on ... | using ...]]
where ...
group by ...
having ...
order by ...
limit ...
```

Except for `select`, all parts are optional.

Better explanation in the mySQL Documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: even `FROM` is optional in MySQL, i.e. `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. There's no need for `FROM dual` as i.e. with Oracle.